# connecting a custom form control to its parent form validation in angular 2

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-components

I recently tried to create my own custom form control using angular 2.
The custom control should have 2 inputs, and edit an existing object with a known structure. For example:

```
class model {
    public fieldOne: number;
    public fieldSec: number;
}
```

I followed the good explanation I found here:
[Guide For Writing custom form controls](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html)

It worked alright except the guide didn't mention how I can connect
custom control form validation to the form that uses it.
Lets look at an simplified example:

The custom control template looks somehow like this:

```
<form>
    <input [(ngModel)]="existingModel.fieldOne">
    <input [(ngModel)]="existingModel.fieldSec" required>
</form>
```

And we use it to edit an existing model which value is:

```
{
    fieldOne: 20,
    fieldSec: undefined
}
```

And we use it in some form in my app where we need the custom control to edit this model:

```
<form #formVar="ngForm">
    <my-custom-control [(ngModel)]="existingModel" required>
    </my-custom-control>
</form>
```

This kind of example works in my app in the matter that I can edit the model.
The problem is that I want to show the user when the form is invalid, and if I look at formVar.valid it will be true even though `existingModel.fieldSec` is undefined and it has a required validation on it in the custom control form.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know exactly how your custom control behaves, but the following solution is valid even if you're dynamically compiling the component itself.

Even in a scenario of template-driven forms (like yours), the underlying engine still works by exploiting reactive components (`FormGroup` and `FormControl`). Thus, you can always programmatically change the hierarchies of groups and child controls to propagate the changes as expected.
You could - for instance - expose among others a property for your custom control accepting an `NgForm`:

```
@Input('form') peerForm : NgForm;
@Input('entity') model : any;
```

Then set the binding in your view:

```
<form #formVar="ngForm">
<my-custom-control [entity]="existingModel" [form]="formVar">
</my-custom-control></form>
```

Your component template should look like:

```
<div>
<input [(ngModel)]="model.fieldOne" #ctrl1="ngModel">
<input [(ngModel)]="model.fieldSec" required #ctrl2="ngModel">
</div>
```

And, again in your component's code:

```
@ViewChild('ctrl1') ngModel1 : NgModel;
@ViewChild('ctrl2') ngModel2 : NgModel;
...
ngAfterViewInit(){
    // assuming the form does exist (TODO: check if set here)
    this.peerForm.control.addControl('entity_fieldOne', this.ngModel1.control);
    this.peerForm.control.addControl('entity_fieldSec', this.ngModel2.control);
}
```

That should suffice. See Plunker here: https://plnkr.co/gb3XroZNoGuZa05e76X0

Comment: Thats how initially solved it. I didn't mention that because I felt its too cumbersome and felt there should be more of a built-in solution for such a common use case

Comment: Thanks. Spent a good few hours trying to find out how to do this!

Comment: So there is no built in solution for this yet?